# How can I type an int index?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I'm working in a C# environment that does not allow use of reference types to reference something. Yes, you're reading that right. I can use structs, and I can use special arrays that are not objects.

To link data, I'm using an index into another, predetermined array. Something like this:

```
static class Data {
    public static float[] Length = new ...;
    public static float[] Weight = new ...;
    // In reality these arrays are NativeArray<T>, provided by the Unity framework
}

int indexLength = 3; // index refers to an entry in the Length array
Data.Length[indexLength] += 1.23;

int indexWeight = 3; // index refers to an entry in the Weight array
Data.Weight[indexWeight] += 1.23;
```

This is, of course, opposed to an object oriented approach, and is a more complicated to keep properly aligned.

To help this effort, I would like to amend indexes such that they 'know' which array they belong to. I guess this is similar to what a *Measure* does in F#, though I have never used that myself yet. It could maybe look like this:

```
WeightIndex indexWeight = (WeightIndex) 3; // The index knows which array it belongs to
Data.Weight[indexWeight] = 42; // OK (maybe implicit cast of indexWeight to int)
Data.Length[indexWeight] = 42; // Compiler error: Wrong index type
```

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Additionally, an optimizing compiler should completely remove it to avoid any runtime overhead. I'm using Burst (an LLVM-based compiler), so this is probably not a problem unless the approach is too complicated for it to understand.

Comment: Is the structure of your `Data` class fixed? Could you use generics?

Comment: @ChrisBD Each field is fixed, I can change nothing about the declaration. But they could be moved into another static class if needed (albeit it would be cumbersome, as such data classes aggregate related data). A containing static class can be changed pretty much at will, it could also be made generic. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you have control over the `NativeArray` class, you can make a variant that takes *two* generic parameters, e.g. a `NativeArray<float, LengthIndex>`. `LengthIndex` would be a struct with a single `int IndexValue { get; }` property. To make sure that `NativeArray` can access the IndexValue property, your second generic parameter (`TIndex`) would be constrained to structs implementing the `IIndex` interface defining that property. The indexer of your special `NativeArray` would then take a `TIndex` instead of an `int`.

Comment: @Heinzi I think there was an misunderstanding. I've used a bad/overly complicated example in the question, I am sorry. I've tried and edited to clarify it now. I believe your idea would work perfectly in another scenario.

Comment: @mafu: Thanks for clarifying. If I understand you correctly, `NativeArray` is a class provided by the Unity framework, so you can't modify it. In that case, you could *still* create a `MyTypedArray<T, TIndex>` struct that encapsulates a `NativeArray<T>` and only allows access through `TIndex` indexes.

Comment: @Heinzi Ah, I get it now. Yes, that seems like it should work quite nicely. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @mafu: Sure, just wrote one. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `MyTypedArray<T, TIndex>` struct that encapsulates an array (or `NativeArray<T>`) and only allows access through `TIndex` indexes.

For example, a `MyTypedArray<float, LengthIndex>` could only be indexed via a `LengthIndex`. `LengthIndex` would be a struct with a single `int IndexValue { get; }` property. To ensure that `MyTypedArray` can access the `IndexValue` property, `TIndex` needs be constrained to structs implementing the `IIndex` interface defining that property. The indexer of `MyTypedArray` then takes a `TIndex` instead of an `int`.

Here's an example implementation ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/69jj9t)):

```
interface IIndex
{
    int IndexValue { get; }
}

readonly struct MyTypedArray<T, TIndex> where TIndex : struct, IIndex
{
    readonly T[] contents;
    
    public T this[TIndex index]
    {
        get => contents[index.IndexValue];
        set => contents[index.IndexValue] = value;
    }
    
    public MyTypedArray(int length) => contents = new T[length];
}

readonly struct LengthIndex : IIndex
{
    public int IndexValue { get; }
    public LengthIndex(int i) => IndexValue = i;
    public static implicit operator LengthIndex(int i) => new LengthIndex(i);
}

readonly struct WidthIndex : IIndex
{
    public int IndexValue { get; }
    public WidthIndex(int i) => IndexValue = i;
    public static implicit operator WidthIndex(int i) => new WidthIndex(i);
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lengths = new MyTypedArray<float, LengthIndex>(4);
        var widths = new MyTypedArray<float, WidthIndex>(4);
        
        LengthIndex indexLength = 3;    // implicit conversion

        lengths[indexLength] += 1.0f;
        // widths[indexLength] += 1.0f; // won't compile: cannot convert from 'LengthIndex' to 'WidthIndex'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was thinking about Generics and potential operator overriding, but then I remembered extension methods.

Here's some code using a static data class with two static arrays (I obviously don't have access to a `NativeArray` type), but it will type check on the value passed to the array.

```
static class DataExtension
{
    public static float Entry(this float[] array, int index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }
    public static void Entry(this float[] array, int index, float value)
    {
        array[index]=value;
    }

    public static int Entry(this int[] array, int index)
    {
        return array[index];
    }
    public static void Entry(this int[] array, int index, int value)
    {
        array[index]=value;
    }
}
```

And its use:

```
static class Data 
{
    public static float[] Length = new float[]{1.0f, 1.1f, 1.2f};
    public static int[] Weight = new int[]{4,5,6};
}
static void Main()
{

    for(var i=0; i< Data.Length.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Length[{i}]={Data.Length[i]}");
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Length.Entry(i) = {Data.Length.Entry(i)}");
        
        Data.Length.Entry(i, Data.Length.Entry(i)+0.5f);
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Length.Entry(i)+0.5f = {Data.Length.Entry(i)}");
        
    }

    for(var i=0; i< Data.Weight.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Weight[{i}]={Data.Weight[i]}");
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Weight.Entry(i) = {Data.Weight.Entry(i)}");
        
        Data.Weight.Entry(i, Data.Weight.Entry(i)+2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Data.Weight.Entry(i)+2 = {Data.Weight.Entry(i)}");
        
    }

}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Data.Length[0]=1
Data.Length.Entry(i) = 1
Data.Length.Entry(i)+0.5f = 1.5
Data.Length[1]=1.1
Data.Length.Entry(i) = 1.1
Data.Length.Entry(i)+0.5f = 1.6
Data.Length[2]=1.2
Data.Length.Entry(i) = 1.2
Data.Length.Entry(i)+0.5f = 1.7
Data.Weight[0]=4
Data.Weight.Entry(i) = 4
Data.Weight.Entry(i)+2 = 6
Data.Weight[1]=5
Data.Weight.Entry(i) = 5
Data.Weight.Entry(i)+2 = 7
Data.Weight[2]=6
Data.Weight.Entry(i) = 6
Data.Weight.Entry(i)+2 = 8
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how this approach works? I do not understand how it prevents access to an array that an index does not belong to - the indexes are regular ints if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm not sure if there was a misunderstanding - I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: Ah. I obviously misunderstood.